# class and paint relationship in OOPS

Tags: oop

this might not be the right place to ask this question as it was asked to me in an interview, but i would like to understand the oops concept behind it.

There are two base classes and a derived class:

```
    class Car {}

    class Paint {}

    class Colors : Paint {}
```

So the question was what is the object oriented concept behind having Paint as a different base class and Colors as sub class to Paint class.

My confusion is that Paint is a base class and not a property of Car class. What OOP's concept is applied here.

Comment: While others may disagree, I believe the "concept" being applied here is called "poor design".

Comment: I think you mean "class and parent object relationships". OOPS = "Object Oriented Programming's". Perhaps you meant OOD = "Object Oriented Design".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept is that some people have no concept.  First, what is a "Colors" (don't name classes with plural names).  What behavior in Paint is inherited by Colors?  Nothing as far as I can see.  I have no clue what Colors is supposed to do.

Can a Color be used interchangeably with Paint? Not that I can imagine.  Right off the bat it seems like a poor class hierarchy.

IMHO, the question is completely bogus.

Comment: I told him that the Object oriencted concept here could be that the Car class composes Paint class. Also separating Paint class from Car could be encapsulation because separate manufacturer or Car makers would have their own set of paint class. But I really have no idea about this design.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason I imagine it was described to you as:

> "You have a `Car` class and a `Paint` class, and the `Paint` class is
>   subclassed by `Colors`."

I'm assuming the person who explained it didn't mean literally a single class named `Colors`. I would imagine it was something more like:

```
    public class Car
    {
    }

    public abstract class Paint
    {
        public abstract void PaintCar(Car car);
    }

    public class BluePaint : Paint
    {
        public override void PaintCar(Car car)
        {
            // apply blue paint to the car
        }
    }

    public class MatteRedPaint : Paint
    {
        public override void PaintCar(Car car)
        {
            // apply red paint to the car
            // use matte finish
        }
    }
```

Which in itself it not quite ideal, but far more plausible than what is suggested by your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like they are looking for the key word: Inheritance

Colors inherits from Paint, right?

Although it would make more sense if Paint inherited from Color.

This was probably one of those open-ended questions looking for an OOP discussion with you.

And if Car `HAS-A` Paint as opposed to Car `IS-A` Paint, well that could possibly be that they are looking for the Strategy design pattern: prefer composition over inheritance. But that example is pushing it a bit, as it doesnt really make sense.

And the last thing they may have been looking for is a discussion related to why you think multiple inheritance is bad. You do think its bad, right? :)